# Spring Boot App is not showing in Axon Dashboard

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, cqrs, axon

I am new to Spring Boot CQRS pattern.

I have a Spring boot app and I am running the Axon server on my localhost using the jar version.

However, my app does not show up in the Axon Dashboard.

[image: Axon Dashboard]

Also I am getting the below error when I try to run my application.

```
Consider defining a bean of type 'org.axonframework.commandhandling.gateway.CommandGateway' in your configuration.
```

My Pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.userws</groupId>
    <artifactId>user-ws</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>user-ws</name>
    <description>user-ws</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>2022.0.0-RC2</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-openfeign</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-data-jpa -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-validation -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.axonframework/axon-spring-boot-starter -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.axonframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>axon-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>4.6.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
            <artifactId>flyway-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
            <artifactId>flyway-mysql</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
            <artifactId>mapstruct</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.3.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.projectlombok/lombok-mapstruct-binding -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok-mapstruct-binding</artifactId>
            <version>0.2.0</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>16</source> <!-- depending on your project -->
                    <target>16</target> <!-- depending on your project -->
                    <annotationProcessorPaths>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                            <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
                            <version>1.5.3.Final</version>
                        </path>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                            <version>1.18.22</version>
                        </path>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok-mapstruct-binding</artifactId>
                            <version>0.2.0</version>
                        </path>
                        <!-- other annotation processors -->
                    </annotationProcessorPaths>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.sonarsource.scanner.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.4.0.905</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>netflix-candidates</id>
            <name>Netflix Candidates</name>
            <url>https://artifactory-oss.prod.netflix.net/artifactory/maven-oss-candidates</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

</project>
```

And the project repository : [Github Repo](https://github.com/RmRaja/springboot_CQRS)

I tried searching on Stackoverflow but could not find any solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Axon Framework doesn't work with Spring Boot 3 [yet](https://github.com/AxonFramework/AxonFramework/issues/2430). We are looking into a solution, so hopefully Axon Framework 4.7.0 will be compatible with Spring Boot 3.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Downgrading spring boot version to 2.7.6 has resolved my issue.

Comment: FYI, 4.7.0 was released a few weeks ago. See also https://developer.axoniq.io/w/axon-framework-4.7-ready-to-use